# Joomla1.5 CRUD extension tutorial

Tags: joomla1.5, crud

I need to build a basic CRUD joomla extension for a customer.

On the user's side, it must display a product list when the user choose a category, and the product details when an item is selected in the list. On the product details page, the user can send a message to the site's owner regarding the chosen product.

On the admin side, user must be able to add/modify/delete products and categories. That's about it.

Does anybody knows (a) good tutorial(s) that could help me get started with this project?

I've worked with php 4 years ago and have 5+ years experience in web development (.net), but i'm new to joomla.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like to me you are looking for an e-commerce extension with a catalog mode (no purchases/no cart enabled) and an Ask a Question form on product pages. I know that at least Virtuemart has this ability exactly. I am sure there are other simpler carts that will also accommodate your need. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart

Spend a couple of hours trying out carts, no code writing required.

Comment: Actually that would be perfect for the time being. I could use it to satisfy my customer and use the spare time to learn a bit more Joomla!

Thanks for the tip Brent.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. There are quite a few newer cart available. Virtuemart has a catalog mode with a send a question form, but it's a pain to use. I would check the others first then us VM if nothing else works.

Comment: Well, I finally did use Virtuemart and it worked perfectly. My client got his site on time but no spare time for me ;). Thanks again

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A great place to start is the Joomla docs site.

Checkout [Component Development section](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development).
Also, here is [MVC Component Tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1) (there are 6 section to it, look for links at the bottom for "Next"), it will definitely put you on the right track. You will have to add a lot of your project specific things and do out of the box things, but it should be pretty easy.

Just keep things separate to make it easier

- **View/Template** - your presentation
- **Controller** - logic
- **Model** - Data Access Layer (DAL)